# Binding custom data structures to DataGrid ItemsSource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ilist, itemssource

I'm trying to bind a custom class to the itemssource member of a WPF DataGrid from c#.  I implemented IList, but for some reason I can't get the list to show any members.

I'm setting the ItemsSource property in C# by calling

```
    dataGridObject.ItemsSource = switchHolderObject
```

Here is the definition for my value:

```
    public class AssetHolder<T> : Dictionary<string,T>, IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : Asset
    {
        ... // lots of code here
        new public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var enumerator = base.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var pair = enumerator.Current;
                yield return pair.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class NonGenericAssetHolder : AssetHolder<Asset> {}
    public class SwitchHolder : NonGenericAssetHolder {}
```

The reason I have three classes here is to get around the fact that dictionaries in C# are not covariant.

I have verified that all my implemented IList methods are working properly, and the list does expand and have the appropriate data, but the DataGrid still shows no members.  The strange thing is that it works when I add this method to the AssetHolder class:

```
    public List<T> Hack()
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        foreach (T asset in this)
        {
            result.Add(asset);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and constantly re-bind the DataGrid like this:

```
    SwitchGrid.ItemsSource = _tempLocation.Switches.Hack();
```

However, that creates a huge performance hit, and I feel like it should work the way it is. Anyone know what's going on?  Why won't the DataGrid show my data?

Comment: Have you implemented the `GetEnumerator()` right? Are you using it? On a side note: I always set the `DataContext` of an `ItemsControl` in code-behind and set the `ItemsSource` in Xaml just to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` this way you have more change of BindingErrors appearing in the output window, so you can diagnose better what's going wrong.

Comment: I guess, it depense on place, where you fill data in AssetHolder class. You must fill it in constructor to use it in the way like this. Or, you can bind ItemsSource to the Hack method, but you should use AssetHolder<T> as return type, IMO: public AssetHolder<T> Hack() { return this; }

Comment: @Silvermind Dictionary implements IEnumerable, so I just modified the GetEnumerator function to return only the values.  I have confirmed that it works properly, and I added it to my post above.

Comment: Have you also confirmed that it works properly when not accessed by code but only by Xaml by putting a breakpoint inside the GetEnumerator? This way we will now if the Xaml triggers it, sorry if you pointed this out already, just making sure.

Comment: @Silvermind modified the binding as you suggested, but unfortunately in this case I still didn't get any BindingErrors.

Comment: @Silvermind Good tip!  Acutally, GetEnumerator is NOT being called.  I read here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx) that ItemsSource prefers IList, but even when I stop implementing IList, GetEnumerator still doesn't get called. Also, when I am implementing IList, my this[] doesn't get called either.

Comment: @JiKra I don't understand what you mean in the first part of your post.  I fill the AssetHolder at runtime; does it need to be done in a constructor?  I have tried constantly running <DataGrid>.Items.Refresh(), but that doesn't help anything, and I have checked to make sure that AssetHolder is actually getting filled.  As for the second suggestion, that didn't work for me.  Since the Hack function would now be returning the AssetHolder object itself, wouldn't that be the same as binding directly to the object without using the method?

Comment: @hypehuman I've updated my answer for completeness ( is that last one a word? :) ) However, should give you a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I'v just implemented the IDictionary interface and added a private variable of Dictionary.

For demonstration purposes I've only used the Add and GetEnumerator in the Interface.
This way we can do this for starters using a testclass Person:

```
AssetHolder<Person> persons = new AssetHolder<Person>( );
persons.Add("One", new Person( ) { FirstName = "Jack" , LastName = "Jobs" , Age = 63 } );
persons.Add( "Two" , new Person( ) { FirstName = "Peter" , LastName = "Lastname" , Age = 33 } );
persons.Add( "Three" , new Person( ) { FirstName = "Wally" , LastName = "Breakfast" , Age = 33 } );
dataGrid1.DataContext = persons;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid1">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Just a quick test, but this is the AssetHolder, look at the GetEnumerator():

```
public class AssetHolder<T> : IDictionary<string , T>
  {

    Dictionary<string , T> dictionary;

    public AssetHolder()
    {
      dictionary = new Dictionary<string , T>( );
  }

    public void Add( string key , T value )
    {
      dictionary.Add( key , value );
    }

    public bool ContainsKey( string key )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException( ); }
    }

    public bool Remove( string key )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public bool TryGetValue( string key , out T value )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public ICollection<T> Values
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException( ); }
    }

    public T this[string key]
    {
      get
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException( );
      }
      set
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException( );
      }
    }

    public void Add( KeyValuePair<string , T> item )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public void Clear( )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public bool Contains( KeyValuePair<string , T> item )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public void CopyTo( KeyValuePair<string , T>[ ] array , int arrayIndex )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public int Count
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException( ); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException( ); }
    }

    public bool Remove( KeyValuePair<string , T> item )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string , T>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string , T>>.GetEnumerator( )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator( )
    {
      return dictionary.Values.GetEnumerator( );
    }
  }
```

Person Class:

```
  public class Person
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int Age { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I have some c# code that calls foreach on AssetHolder, but now it's telling me that it can't convert from KeyValuePair to AssetObject. How do I specify which GetEnumerator to use?

Comment: But yay! It works! I'm not sure why my original solution didn't work, but I'm glad that this one does.

Comment: I did a little more testing and this is what I learned: properly sending notification events (or removing the INotify interfaces) was necessary to get anything to show in the DataGrid.  But just doing that was not enough, because my code was still returning KeyValuePairs as foreach results.  Your typeless GetEnumerator method was required to make each result show as a single Asset object.

Comment: @hypehuman I guess that implementing the IList does not override the GetEnumerator of the derived Dictionary. Nice thing it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  The reason my implementation didn't work is because I included the INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces, but I was not explicitly telling it when to notify.  When I stopped implementing them, it magically worked!